# How to make a limit points by month in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my new rails project,I want to limit the user's post number by something like point.At the begining of every month,every user was given limited points.When user use up their points,they can't do any thing.

My question is,how to give user this points at the begining of every month automatically in Rails?How to design the model and controller?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use something like [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to schedule your tasks.
Here is '[monthly jobs syntax question](http://groups.google.com/group/whenever-gem/browse_thread/thread/cf91d831f288f3f2?pli=1)' from whenever mailing list. In general  you will have something like:

```
# shedule.rb
every 1.month, :at => "beginning of the month at 3am" do
  runner "User.set_points" # or rake "task:for:user:set_poins" if you have rake task for this
end

# user.rb
def self.set_points
  User.all.each{|u| u.update_attribute(:points, some_function_to_calculate_points(u)}
end
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: OMG!I love [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever).Thank you @santuxus and also thank the author of Whenever.